# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Filter shader link failed'

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I need to show live camera feed. I used GPUImage, when i execute the code i'm getting this error. I referred some document and i written code in viewDidLoad. when i open the app, it crashing.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

    GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomShader"];
    GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    // Add the view somewhere so it's visible

    [videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
    [customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];

    }
```

Log:

```
Failed to load vertex shader
  Failed to compile fragment shader
 Program link log: ERROR: OpenGL ES 2.0 requires exactly one vertex and one fragment shader to validly link.
 Fragment shader compile log: (null)
 Vertex shader compile log: (null)
  *** Assertion failure in -[GPUImageFilter initWithVertexShaderFromString:fragmentShaderFromString:], /Users/ranganathagv/Projects/MobileApp/test/iOS/View/28May_GPU/BradLarson-GPUImage-f67cbd9/framework/Source/GPUImageFilter.m:76
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Filter shader link failed'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Got a crash when using GPUImageFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041627/got-a-crash-when-using-gpuimagefilter)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the shaders have been added to your Copy Bundle Resources build phase. By default, Xcode tries to compile them as source code files, rather than include them in your application bundle like they should be.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please explain how to check?

Comment: select the Build Phases in the Targets and add the shader files in Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: check this image... you have to add the necessary files here.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1649/Art/qa1649_copyBundle.png

Comment: Here they adding .plist file. So, which one should i add? shader file.h?

Comment: this one has an answer here check this plz.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18047868/3615320

Comment: I have added my project-Info.plist file to copy bundle resources. But still i get crash

Comment: plz add the file. The image is just an example to show where you have to add it. In copy bundle resources you have to add the required files.

Comment: I don't have fragment and vertex shader file in folder.

Comment: plz do check this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041627/got-a-crash-when-using-gpuimagefilter

Comment: I no need any filter to use. I need to show live video view..Which one should i use? Please help