# Assertion failure in -[GPUImageFilter initWithVertexShaderFromString:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gpuimage

Got error as follow

> *** Assertion failure in -[GPUImageFilter initWithVertexShaderFromString:fragmentShaderFromString:],
>   /Users/XYZ/Downloads/GPUImage-master/framework/Source/GPUImageFilter.m:94

I have already set as per mention in https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage after setting framework path and all other thing wrote following code for testing but getting above error.

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomShader"];
GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight)];

// Add the view somewhere so it's visible

[videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
[customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

please help me to solve this...

Comment: Check this link. Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041627/got-a-crash-when-using-gpuimagefilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSAssert(NO, @"Filter shader link failed");
```

your link "CustomShader" is wrong. Do you have `CustomShader.fsh` in your project?

Comment: Yeah, actually we've written that code by mistake for custom filter after your help changed to sepia effect and runs without error